# catch all exceptions angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to catch all exceptions angularjs 
same

```
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
    alert("Error occured: " + errorMsg);//or any message
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code block into the config .you will catch all the angularjs error here.

```
   $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", ["$delegate", "$window", function ($delegate, $window) {
         return function (exception, cause) {
             $delegate(exception, cause);
         };
     }]);
```

Comment: not logical it's not coupled with anything. How it will work.